# How do I make one folder accessible to multiple users?

Tags: permissions, files

I have a folder called servers, and I need to make it, and all its contents accessible to both surge and minecraft.

I tried

```
chmod -R minecraft+surge servers
```

it replies

```
chmod: invalid mode: ‘minecraft+surge’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Permissions are cool](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes). There are two ways to do this:

#### User Groups

The "UNIX way" to do this is to create a new group `servermanagers` or similar, and make that the folder's owning group:

```
sudo groupadd servermanagers
sudo usermod -aG servermanagers minecraft
sudo usermod -aG servermanagers surge
sudo chown -R :servermanagers servers/
sudo chmod 755 servers/
```

You could also just use the `surge` or `minecraft` default groups and just set either of those groups as the owner (though this may do some *interesting* permission things). However, it gets annoying to have groups for this, so enter...

#### ACLs

If your system supports ACLs (EXT4 hard drives will automatically do this), you can just [use an ACL](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists):

```
sudo setfacl -Rm u:minecraft:rwx servers/
sudo setfacl -Rm u:surge:rwx servers/
sudo getfacl -a servers/ | sudo setfacl -d -M- servers/
```

Of course, be sure that your system supports ACLs. See `man setfacl` for more information.